# java Recursion row

Tags: java, recursion, matrix

i'm getting lost, could someone of you please help me?

i want my function "oddEvenRow" to check if the values in row index 0,2,4 are odd. if so return true, if not return false

this is the code i wrote :

```
public class Matrix
{
    public static int temp=0;
    public static boolean oddEvenRow (int[][]a, int r, int c, int count)
    {
        if(r>4&&count==12) {
            temp=1;
            return false;
        }
        if(a[r][c]%2==0) {
            temp=1;
            return false;
        }
        else {        
            count++;
            if(c==3)                
                oddEvenRow(a,r+2,0,count);
            else
                oddEvenRow(a,r,c+1,count);                
            return true; 
        }    
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int r=0;
        int c=0;
        int count=0;
        int[][]a=new int[5][4];
        a[0][0]=1;
        a[0][1]=3;
        a[0][2]=7;
        a[0][3]=15;
        a[1][0]=4;
        a[1][1]=15;
        a[1][2]=2;
        a[1][3]=9;
        a[2][0]=11;
        a[2][1]=21;
        a[2][2]=1;
        a[2][3]=45;
        a[3][0]=8;
        a[3][1]=15;
        a[3][2]=8;
        a[3][3]=12;
        a[4][0]=7;
        a[4][1]=3;
        a[4][2]=25;
        a[4][3]=21;
        System.out.println(oddEvenRow(a,r,c,count));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're posting a fact, not a question.

Comment: I got lost with `temp=0`... what is the question again?

Comment: To understand recursion, you have to understand recursion first.

Comment: the question is how do i return true if all the values in row 0 , 2 , 4 are odd and how do i return false if it's not

Comment: why would you use recursion for that anyway? why not 2 loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the part with `count` is redundant as you are checking all rows in `r` variable - after the last significant row (4th) the method will return. You do not need checking if there were 12 numbers checked.

What is more `temp` variable acts as return value in your code which you are actually returning with the method itself - also redundant.

I do not see the point in checking already defined number of values using recursion but if you need so consider the following:

```
    public static boolean oddRow(int[][] a, int r, int c) {

        //checking if we checked all rows
        if (r > 4) {
            return true;
        }
        //checking if all columns in row were checked and moving to r+2 row
        if (c > 3) {
            return oddRow(a, r + 2, 0);
        }
        //checking if current value is odd - if yes, keep checking the rest / if not, return false
        return (a[r][c] % 2 == 0) ? oddRow(a, r, c + 1) : false;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at your code, i suspect you meant your question to say "if ALL values in rows 0,2, and 4 are odd..."]

Anyway, you're setting the short circuit variable 'temp' but never using it.  Try adding a check to the top of your function...

```
if(temp == 1)
    return false;
```